# updating dll in the gac via windows installer

Tags: windows, dll, gac

How to replace a strong named DLL in GAC by the windows installer?

I am having two installers that shared some common DLLs from the GAC.

suppose there is any change in any common DLL then 
running any one installer with latest DLL is not replacing the existing DLL.

from some old post, it is suggested that changing file assembly version will replace DLL.
that approach is not working. Is there anything else needs to be done apart from that?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer will not update an assembly in the GAC if you only change the assembly file version unless your install authoring tool also sets the fileVersion attribute for the assembly in the MsiAssemblyName table of the new MSI.

Aaron Stebner addresses this in his  [blog posting.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/10/8847259.aspx)

I know that this works when using WiX, as I've done this in several installers.  I don't know how this might be done in other authoring tools.